# Why top:0 with position:absolute not working if another element has margin-top here?

Tags: html, css

Why `top:0` with `position:absolute` not working here?

I want to mention that in this condition I don't have control on any other element other than `.heatmap`

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.section1 {
  margin-top: 107px;
  border: 1px solid green
}

.heatmap {
  z-index: 2147483642;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1425px;
  height: 1110px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">something</div>

<div class="heatmap">hamara heatmap</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you define "not working"? It looks exactly as I'd expect it to. What do you expect to see?

Comment: becasue body is starting from the section1 .. beacuse of margin

Comment: add display:inline-block to **.section1**

Comment: @AndyHolmes — It already *has* position: relative on its parent.

Comment: @boltclock - I think my question is different.

Comment: @Quentin I misunderstood so removed my comment

Comment: I love how this question is being downvoted, all the while only a few answers appear to grasp what is really going on. I'd say that makes this a good question. Why is it being downvoted?

Comment: @DecentDabbler Thanks for understanding. and also my question is different than marked duplicate

Answer (score 5):

You have encountered [collapsing margins](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/).

`heatmap` is positioned with respect to the nearest ancestor which has `position` that is *not* `static`. This is the `body` element.

The first child of the `body` has a `margin-top`.

That margin collapses through the top of the `body` and pushes the body element down away from the viewport edge.

You can see this by applying an outline to the body element.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: solid pink 10px;
}

.section1 {
  margin-top: 107px;
  border: 1px solid green
}

.heatmap {
  z-index: 2147483642;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1425px;
  height: 1110px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">something</div>

<div class="heatmap">hamara heatmap</div>
```

To avoid this, prevent the margins from collapsing. This is most easily done by using padding on the body instead of margin on the heatmap.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 107px 0 0 0;
  outline: solid pink 10px;
}

.section1 {
  border: 1px solid green
}

.heatmap {
  z-index: 2147483642;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1425px;
  height: 1110px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">something</div>

<div class="heatmap">hamara heatmap</div>
```

Comment: I have no control on other elements in the page other than heatmap. I think i will have to use `fixed` instead `absolute`

Comment: @JitendraVyas — A hack which shouldn't have the side effects of `fixed` would be to set `top: -107px`.

Comment: but I don't always know the value of margin. it can be different on different website.

Comment: and by the way what cons could be possible with `fixed`?

Comment: It permanently uses up a portion of the viewport. Links to specific parts of the page will result in the content being linked to being covered up by the fixed element.

Comment: What I want is the nothing below `.heatmap` should be clickable in the presence of `.heatmap`

Answer (score 0):

You just remove `position: relative` from `body`, it will work

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.section1 {
  margin-top: 107px;
  border: 1px solid green
}

.heatmap {
  z-index: 2147483642;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1425px;
  height: 1110px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">something</div>

<div class="heatmap">hamara heatmap</div>
```

Comment: but I can't remove that

Comment: Although this appears to work, to me, this seems completely counter-intuitive. Is `<body>` some special case, perhaps? I'd expect `.heatmap` to appear at the "absolute" top of the page, disregarding the `top-margin` of the body's first child.

Comment: you can use `position: initial` instead of `relative`

Answer (score 0):

Just give **padding-top: 1px;** to **body** and it will work fine;

The problem was margin given to section1 which cause *collapsing margin*

See this link:

https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/

Comment: This does work but in this instance the OP can't control the `body`

Comment: i don't think you can achieve what you want without changing css for other elements like body etc.

Comment: You can also use `body::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1px;
}`

Comment: Again, the OP can't control the `body` *only* `.heatmap`. Besides, `body:before` in some cases may already have a usage